# Sorting TV Shows (Python)

Tags: python

Working on Zybook Lab. This is what they want. The formatting of the question isn't great here.

> Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the input file using the file.readlines() method. The input file contains an unsorted list of number of seasons followed by the corresponding TV show. Your program should put the contents of the input file into a dictionary where the number of seasons are the keys, and a list of TV shows are the values since multiple shows could have the same number of seasons).
>
> Sort the dictionary by key (least to greatest) and output the results to a file named output_keys.txt, separating multiple TV shows associated with the same key with a semicolon (;). Next, sort the dictionary by values (alphabetical order), and output the results to a file named output_titles.txt.
>
> Ex: If the input is: file1.txt
>
> and the contents of file1.txt are:
>
> > 20
> > Gunsmoke
> > 30
> > The Simpsons
> > 10
> > Will & Grace
> > 14
> > Dallas
> > 20
> > Law & Order
> > 12
> > Murder, She Wrote
>
> the file output_keys.txt should contain:
>
> > 10: Will & Grace
> > 12: Murder, She Wrote
> > 14: Dallas
> > 20: Gunsmoke; Law &
> > Order 30: The Simpsons
> > and the file output_titles.txt should contain:
>
> Dallas Gunsmoke Law & Order Murder, She Wrote The Simpsons Will &
> Grace Note: There is a newline at the end of each output file, and
> file1.txt is available to download.

Here is my code so far.

```
def readFile(filename):
    dict = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        for index in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2):
            if lines[index].strip()=='':
                continue
            count = int(lines[index].strip())
            name = lines[index + 1].strip()
            if count in dict.keys():
                dict[count].append(name)
            else:
                dict[count] = [name]
    return dict

def output_keys(dict, filename):
    with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:
        for key in sorted(dict.keys()):
            outfile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))
            print('{}: {}'.format(key,'; '.join(dict.get(key))))

def output_titles(dict, filename):
    titles = []
    for title in dict.values():
        titles.extend(title)
    with open(filename,'w+') as outfile:
        for title in sorted(titles):
            outfile.write('{}\n'.format(title))
            print(title)

def main():
    filename = input()
    dict = readFile(filename)
    if dict is None:
        print('Error: Invalid file name provided: {}'.format(filename))
        return

output_filename_1 ='output_keys.txt'
output_filename_2 ='output_titles.txt'
output_keys(dict,output_filename_1)
print()
output_titles(dict,output_filename_2)

main()
```

I keep getting an error though.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 40, in 
> output_keys(dict,output_filename_1)   File "main.py", line 18, in output_keys
> for key in sorted(dict.keys()): TypeError: descriptor 'keys' of 'dict' object needs an argument

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dict` is a built-in class, don't use it as a variable name. It makes `output_keys(dict,output_filename_1)` seem fine - but `dict` is not a variable known when you call this. Or is your code formatted incorrectly?

Comment: Right.  Those 5 lines just above "main()" need to be indented, so they are part of the `main` function.

Comment: @TimRoberts that is exactly my problem thank you.